# how to create image slider for homepage in magento?

Tags: magento

i use the mangeto 1.9 and platform community.
how to configure the slideshow in homepage?
install the MA2 theme in magento. 
this is MA2 theme link:"http://www.magenmarket.com/ma2-juno-multi-purpose-theme-for-magento-store.html"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the theme provide the slider.You can use the slider extensions.

Check this out may work for you.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/banner-slider-magento.html

Comment: i use this extension but this error generate "CONNECT ERROR: Package 'Magestore_BannerSlider' is invalid
'./app/code/community\Magestore\Bannerslider\Block\Adminhtml\Bannerslider\Edit\Tab\Content\Categories.php' already exists"

Comment: Check in your admin panel in "system->Configuration" for banner slider it may already be there.If not try out clearing your cache and try again or try any other slider

Comment: i use this banner extension"http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/banner-slider-6.html" but how to display in home page or other category page? and plz u send me configuration for homepage

Comment: I think the banner slider you choose doesnot have the feature to choose the place to show. use this extension and see the images provided in the link for the setting. http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/banner-slider-10.html

Comment: oky thanks this banner extension use for me